# rendering html in a sequence through a single controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to displaying multiple strings one after the other via same controller action?

For e.g. I want to display the paraTwo string after paraOne string is loaded and displayed on the view, paraThree string after paraTwo is loaded on the view and so on.

```
Public ActionResult ChapterOne()
{

string paraOne = "This is paragraph one ";

string paraTwo = "This is paragraph two";

string paraThree = "This is paragraph three";

string paraFour = "This is paragraph four";

return View();

}
```

Comment: create a model which holds the paraOne to paraFour string properties. Create a view and display your paras...in which order you need

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ Is there a limit to the string size which I can pass to a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `model`

```
public class Paragraph
{
    public string paraOne { get; set; }
    public string paraTwo { get; set; }
    public string paraThree { get; set; }
    public string paraFour { get; set; }
}
```

In the `Action`

```
public ActionResult ChapterOne()
    {
        var paragraph = new Paragraph
        {
            paraOne = "This is paragraph one ",
            paraTwo = "This is paragraph two",
            paraThree = "This is paragraph three",
            paraFour = "This is paragraph four"
        };
        return View(paragraph);
    }
```

In the `View`

```
 @model Paragraph

 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "Chapter One";
 }

<h2>Chapter One</h2>

<p>@Model.paraOne</p>
<p>@Model.paraTwo</p>
<p>@Model.paraThree</p>
<p>@Model.paraFour</p>
```

Comment: what is the max string size we can pass to a view from controller?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `List<string>` to add paragraphs in sequence

```
var listparas= new List<string>();

listparas.Add("This is paragraph one ");

listparas.Add("This is paragraph two");

listparas.Add("This is paragraph three");

listparas.Add("This is paragraph four");

return View(listparas);
```

and in `view`

```
@model List<string>

 foreach (var paragraph in Model)
    {
         <p>@paragraph</p>
    }
```

if you are using viewmodel you can add

```
    public List<string> ParaList { get; set; }
```

and you can iterate over it by `Model.ParaList` in `foreach`

Comment: is there a limit to string size that we can pass to a view from controller?

Comment: @user793468 it does not have limit

Comment: I ask because the strings are huge(over 40k in length total) and IE hangs after about 3 minutes of loading. Any suggestions/ideas on how I should render such a large html?

Comment: @user793468 you can use pagination to load half string in one page and half on another and so on